# What's the point to log in as root and do “su - user” instead of log in as user?

Tags: linux, ssh, su

I have to redo a bash script (not originally written by me) and at some point there is an ssh connection with the user "root" and the first thing after that is :

```
su - otheruser
```

I don't really understand why not simply login as otheruser in the ssh and I have both passwords for root and otheruser.

Is there any (even small) differences path wise of something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is (at least) one possible reason. Admin configure ssh to be permitted only with key and the only account with key is root. So you login as root and then switch to other user.

Another reason can be restriction via sshd_config the users, permitted to login via ssh.

Comment: Also sometimes certain actions should be verified or executed from behalf of another user (e.g. some daemons manually launched or permissions checked). Many people are too lazy to relogin. And most of them are lazy enough to enter passwords :)

Comment: Note that the one with the root account, could also easily grant any other user the right to log in using such key as well. (But then more keys need to be managed.)

Comment: Right, @Arjan. But for some reason admin can decide to limit access only to root. I have such machines in one of the environment I work on

Comment: The thing is I can use ssh on both users. How do I check the used key when I'm connected ?

Comment: if you exec ssh -v user@host you will see if its authenticated by password or key

Comment: I'm using putty to connect to a linux system and I tried to give the "-v" arg but nothing showed up (the bash script is given by putty btw)

Comment: try to set log of the sessions